Hide datagrid cell based on Model property
Having this model:
public class OptimizationSetting
 {
   public bool Selected { get; set; }
   public string SettingName { get; set; }
   public bool HasValue { get; set; }
   public double Value { get; set; }
 }

And this xaml page:
<DataGrid BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding OptimizationSettings}" Margin="1" IsReadOnly="False" Background="White"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="20"
      CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding Selected}" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Setting" Binding="{Binding SettingName}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

I'm trying to hide the DataGrid Value content based on the model HasValue value. Can I achieve this by using styles?

You can hide the content of a cell but not the cell itself because there is the column.

Yes, that is what I was trying to achieve. Just to hide the content of one cell

You can find several ways to hide the content of a cell. The following is one example.
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValue, Mode=OneTime}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>

